# SQL: Selecting same Table Column twice based on different WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have already tried various proposed solutions here but none of them have proposed what I need.

I need one result of 2 Queries with each one WHERE condition of 1 Table. No Union result please. Both query results need to be in different Columns packed in one result. Let me show you what I mean:

Query 1:

[image: This is the result from the first query]

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung AS Abteilung, 
    COUNT(tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id) AS [Offene Abteilungstermine] 
FROM 
    tbl_Lieferschein
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Positionen ON tbl_Lieferschein.lieferschein_id = tbl_Positionen.id_lieferschein
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen.positionen_id = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_abteilungen = tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id
WHERE 
    tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.fertiggestellt = 0 
    AND tbl_Lieferschein.fertiggestellt = 0 
    AND tbl_Lieferschein.gelöscht = 0
GROUP BY 
    tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung
```

Query 2:

[image: This is the result from the second query]

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id) AS [Überfällige Abteilungstermine] 
FROM
    tbl_Lieferschein
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Positionen ON tbl_Lieferschein.lieferschein_id = tbl_Positionen.id_lieferschein
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen.positionen_id = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_abteilungen = tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id
WHERE 
    tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.fertiggestellt = 0 
    AND tbl_Lieferschein.fertiggestellt = 0 
    AND tbl_Lieferschein.gelöscht = 0 
    AND tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.Abteilungstermin < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
GROUP BY 
    tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung
```

All I need is a result like the following:

Needed result:

[image: Needed result]

PS: The best would be, if all null results would be shown as '0'

Comment: Use `coalesce(column, 0)` to replace null values with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got two queries that you then join together on `tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung`

So like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(A.Abteilung, B.Abteilung) AS Abteilung, ISNULL(A.[Offene Abteilungstermine],0) AS [Offene Abteilungstermine], 
    ISNULL(B.[Überfällige Abteilungstermine],0) AS [Überfällige Abteilungstermine]
FROM (SELECT tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung AS Abteilung, 
      COUNT(tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id) AS [Offene Abteilungstermine] 
      FROM tbl_Lieferschein
      INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen ON tbl_Lieferschein.lieferschein_id =           tbl_Positionen.id_lieferschein
      INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen.positionen_id = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
      INNER JOIN tbl_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_abteilungen = tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id
      WHERE tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.fertiggestellt = 0 
      AND tbl_Lieferschein.fertiggestellt = 0 
      AND tbl_Lieferschein.gelöscht = 0
      GROUP BY tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung) A
FULL OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung AS Abteilung, COUNT(tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id) AS [Überfällige Abteilungstermine] 
      FROM tbl_Lieferschein
      INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen ON tbl_Lieferschein.lieferschein_id = tbl_Positionen.id_lieferschein
      INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen.positionen_id = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
      INNER JOIN tbl_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_abteilungen = tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id
      WHERE tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.fertiggestellt = 0 
      AND tbl_Lieferschein.fertiggestellt = 0 
      AND tbl_Lieferschein.gelöscht = 0 AND tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.Abteilungstermin < cast(GETDATE() AS DATE)
      GROUP BY tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung) B
ON A.Abteilung = B.Abteilung
```

i.e. your two queries as sub-queries, with a FULL OUTER JOIN. Note that in the second query I've added `tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung AS Abteilung` as a SELECT column to make the join possible.

Comment: Wow, that was really quick. Thank you very much, its is exactly what I was looking for :) Very appreciated!!

Comment: No probs. I just edited an added an ISNULL on the first column, I think that might be needed for when there's a B with no matching A.

Comment: Noticed, works like a charm. Thanks for your fantastic, plus for me very valuable input.

Comment: Maybe you can help me out with this again: I need to count MIN(tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.Abteilungstermin) not the abteilungen.id.

`COUNT(MIN(tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.Abteilungstermin)) AS [Offene Abteilungstermine] ` 
unfortunately doesnt work in SQL.

Comment: @Karol COUNT(MIN()) doesn't make any sense - the minimum of a column is the single lowest value, so there's nothing to count. What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Oh yea there is a bunch to count. Its a department table related to a offer table. Each offer has multiple departments, each departments have a date untill they need to finish a subtask. All I need to count is the department of each offer with the lowest date. So lets say I have 100 offers, each offer has 5 different departments, each with a date: Now I need to sum the departments if they have the lowest date of all 5 deparments. An example below in the next comment:

Comment: `Jacket ( 1st offer)
1. Department Construct (27.11.2019) 
2. Department Build (30.11.2019)
3. Department Store (01.12.2019)

Trousers (2nd offer)
1. Department Construct (01.12.2019)
2. Department Store (05.12.2019)
3. Department Deploying (08.12.2019)`

As you see in my little example only Construct has the lowest date in both offers, only Construct need to be summed up -> Construct: 2, Build: 0, Store: 0. Thats what the result should look like. So its basically not to count the IDs but the MIN(Dates). I hope you did understand what I mean :-)

Comment: @Karol - I think you want to find the minimum accross a few columns? Its hard to figure it in comments, maybe start a new question, or we could talk here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203091/sql-abteilungstermincounting

Comment: I have joined the chat.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you use the CASE statement in your select clause and then count only those that match your date parameter as below.

```
SELECT Abteilung, 
        SUM([Offene Abteilungstermine]) AS [Offene Abteilungstermine],
        SUM([Überfällige Abteilungstermine]) AS [Überfällige Abteilungstermine]
FROM (
    SELECT tbl_Abteilungen.Bezeichnung AS Abteilung,
        [Offene Abteilungstermine] = 1,
        [Überfällige Abteilungstermine] = 
                CASE WHEN tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.Abteilungstermin < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                                THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END
    FROM tbl_Lieferschein
    INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen ON tbl_Lieferschein.lieferschein_id = tbl_Positionen.id_lieferschein
    INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen.positionen_id = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
    INNER JOIN tbl_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_abteilungen = tbl_Abteilungen.abteilungen_id
    WHERE tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.fertiggestellt = 0 
    AND tbl_Lieferschein.fertiggestellt = 0 
    AND tbl_Lieferschein.gelöscht = 0
) counts
GROUP BY Abteilung
```

Comment: This is a good idea and makes the most of the similarities between the queries, likely to be more efficient than my answer

Comment: Another great approach, thank you very much for this. Very appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

[If both of the queries have the same Grouped by column
 use CTE's.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

In the below code i have constructed an example.

```
WITH ds1
 AS (SELECT s.CustomerID, 
            SUM(s.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
     FROM dbo.Sales s
     WHERE s.Quantity > 700
     GROUP BY s.CustomerID),
 ds2
 AS (SELECT s.CustomerID, 
            COUNT(1) AS NR, 
            SUM(s.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
     FROM dbo.Sales s
     WHERE s.Quantity < 500
     GROUP BY s.CustomerID)
 SELECT c.FirstName, 
        c.LastName, 
        d.TotalQuantity QuantityFrom1stQuery, 
        d2.TotalQuantity QuantityFrom2ndQuery
 FROM dbo.Customers c
      JOIN ds1 d ON d.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
      JOIN ds2 d2 ON d2.CustomerID = c.CustomerID;
```